# What is the logic behind subtracting the index in stuart and kevin functions to count vowels?

Tags: python, indexing

Title: Understanding  code snippet for calculating countStuart and countKevin

Body:

In the following code snippet, there are two functions stuart(string) and kevin(string) that calculate some count values based on the given string:

```
def stuart(string):
    count = 0
    length = len(string)
    for i in range(length):
        if string[i] not in "AEIOU":
            count += length - i
    return count

def kevin(string):
    count = 0
    length = len(string)
    for i in range(length):
        if string[i] in "AEIOU":
            count += length - i
    return count
```

I'm trying to understand why the index i is subtracted from the length variable inside the count += length - i statements. Specifically, why does the code subtract the index instead of just adding the value alone? Can someone explain the rationale behind this subtraction operation?

Additionally, in the minion_game(string) function, the countStuart and countKevin variables are assigned the values returned by stuart(string) and kevin(string) respectively. These values are then used to determine the output. If there are any insights regarding the purpose or behavior of this code, they would be appreciated as well.

Thank you in advance for your help and explanations!

Comment: This is just a random piece of code calculating some values. Noone will tell you why whoever wrote this code wrote it that way without knowing the context.

Comment: It's difficult to explain this code as very few of the contributors to stack**overflow** are psychic. What is clear is that whoever wrote that code is unfamiliar with traditional Python concepts